# How can I 'verify' my solana metaplex token?

Tags: metaplex, spl-token, fungible-token

Since the solana tokenlist is deprecated I have to use the metaplex token standard to create my tokens. The problem is that even though the tokens are properly displayed inside my wallet now, they're marked as 'unveryfied'. Please help me to solve this issue, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "verification process" right now of tokens. The banner displayed is there to warn the users that there can be duplicated token name/symbol/logo and to double check the mint address.